# DD4T Issue : com.tridion.dynamiccontent.PageContentAssembler

Tags: 2013, dd4t

[image]

I have installed DD4T Tridion Templates and Published to broker Tridion 2013 2013 SP1. Its working fine. But when I execute the DD4T Application, it's throwing error:

Below are the DD4T log file:

```
2016-07-09 15:13:59,656 [18] DEBUG Performance [(null)] - about to load page content from provider with url /index.aspx
2016-07-09 15:13:59,656 [18] DEBUG Performance [(null)] - >>GetContentByUrl(/index.aspx)
2016-07-09 15:13:59,656 [18] DEBUG Performance [(null)] - GetContentByUrl: about to create query
2016-07-09 15:13:59,656 [18] DEBUG Performance [(null)] - GetContentByUrl: created query
2016-07-09 15:13:59,656 [18] DEBUG Performance [(null)] - GetContentByUrl: added criteria to query
2016-07-09 15:13:59,656 [18] DEBUG Performance [(null)] - GetContentByUrl: about to execute query
2016-07-09 15:13:59,660 [18] DEBUG Performance [(null)] - GetContentByUrl: executed query
```

Comment: Please check you have all required jar files and also check the java version you are using.

Comment: Thanks RajeshG. I deployed the updated jar files. Its not working properly.

Comment: Are there any errors in the cd_core.log?

Comment: Check the tridion license, mostly seems it is not able to find license file.

Answer (score -1):

Things you can verify,

1. Check the lib folder if you have the jar named 'cd_dynamic.jar' (Check the version also)
2. Check, if 'cd_dynamic_conf.xml' is present or not in config folder
3. Check if 'cd_wai_conf.xml' file from config folder (It may happen if this xml is not present similar errors may come on query execution, in this case check for the 'cd_wai.jar' jar file also in lib directory)

Additionally you can check the license file (validity) and cd_storage_conf.xml file to re-verify the connections. It seems like you are missing a jar/xml.

Let me know if this helps !!

Answer (score -1):

Looking at the errors, most likely the URL `http://localhost:56` is not mapped to any publication ID in the cd_dynamic_conf.xml file (webapp/bin/config/cd_dynamic_conf.xml)